# How to set background color based on bool property in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, c#-3.0, styles

I want to set the backgroun color for a GridViewColumn that is databound inside of a listview in WPF. I'm not sure how to ask this question being fairly new to WPF, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered all of you.

I want to change the background color of the whole row, based on a bool flag in my databound object.

In this case, I have, well, a "CaseDetail" object, that when there are internal notes "IsInternalNote" I want the color of the row to change.

How can I pull this off in WPF?

What I have now, ( very simple ), which does NOT change the color.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=MMM dd\, yyyy h:mm tt}" Header="Date" Width="Auto" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SubmittedBy}" Header="Submitted By" Width="Auto" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Description" x:Name="colDesc">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>                              
                                <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="80" Width="300">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"  TextWrapping="Wrap"   />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding File.FileName}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ScrollViewer>                             
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>                    
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I ran into a few troubles trying to do this, ended up like so

```
<ListBox ...>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Border x:Name="BGBorder">
         <!-- --> 
      </Border>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
          Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsAborted, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
          Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="BGBorder" Value="Red">
          </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

There may be alternatives, but once I had it working, I stopped looking :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this yet so it might need some tweaks but you're going to want to trigger off the value to set your background color.

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsInternalNote" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Trigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```